# Redirect reputation option for answers derived from other user's attempts/answers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, reputation

Recently I had a question regarding buffers and my question was not worded in the best manner, after some answers and a string of comments, we were able to derive the problem, however it was not really related to the original question.

After an attempt to edit the question to fit the solution, it ended up making the entire question/answer relation off. See [Displaying Buffer overlap in ArcGIS Pro with Intersect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155453/displaying-buffer-overlap-in-arcgis-pro-with-intersect).

I decided to create a new question that was more applicable to the actual problem I was experiencing, and then post the solution to it in the "Answer my own question" format for others to benefit from. See [Coordinate Projection Issue in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155608/coordinate-projection-issue-in-arcgis-pro/155609#155609).

However, I do not think that it is fair that I receive the reputation for an answer that was not my original solution, rather a solution from another use in the first question that I had asked.

Despite my efforts to give the user credit in the answer, I would really like to see a way (especially with the "Answer my own question" format) to redirect the reputation towards the user that is actually responsible for the solution to the problem.

If there is some way that a feature could be implemented to assign a percentage or even the full amount of reputation the deserving user, I would really like to see that incorporated. Potentially if there were a couple of people who contributed to finding the solution they could be compensated accordingly.

I think that this feature would promote a sense of the site being used to help generate answers to issues from a wide base of users, and provide some useful insight to some overlooked issues that a large amount of users may experience.

Maybe there are some drawbacks to this type of idea, I am open to hear any thoughts in regards to this type of a feature.

Comment: You can credit the other user in your answer, the user with original solution can be upvoted (once per user per answer)

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called a ["bounty."](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: I set this to status [meta-tag:status-deferred] because you'll need to convince [meta.se] rather than us here at [meta.gis.se] i.e. it's deferred to a higher authority.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @whuber:

> The feature you are looking for is called a
>   ["bounty."](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

It is great that you are thinking about how the site works, and how it may work better.  While your idea sounds appealing at first, I think there are two strikes against it:

- It would add additional functionality to a reward system that is already complex, but "tried and true", which means that there would have to be a very compelling reason to do it.
- Reputation may seem important at first, but as you garner more of it, I think you will come to see that what drives people to contribute here is not the reputation gained but the good feeling that comes from helping others, and knowing that by helping them now, you are likely to be helped when you are searching, and possibly asking, for a solution to a problem you are stuck on in the future.

I'm sure that I have seen similar suggestions raised on Meta SE (where suggestions for SE network-wide enhancements, that this would be, should always be raised cautiously) but the closest thing that I could find in my search just now was:

[Collaborative Answers / Point-Sharing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/collaborative-answers-point-sharing)